# How to turn column of four digit years entered in general format into a date column or yyyy simply

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

How to turn column of four digit years entered in general format into a date column or yyyy simply? I have a column of two digit months 1-12 and a column of four digit years and then found I should have used a date format. I would like two convert these hundreds and hundreds of entries into a useful date format with a formula or minimum of fuss or programming logic so I can perform useful analysis on the data and don't have to manually re-enter large amounts of data.
I have excel 2007

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you trying to put these together into one cell that is a date?

Comment: That would be a good solution. I need to protect the first cell as well as it has the column type.

Answer (score 2):

Use on of the following formulas in an unused column's row 2,

```
=DATEVALUE("1/1/"&A2)   '<~~ 01-Jan-2015 when 2015 in A2
=DATE(A2, 1, 1)         '<~~ 01-Jan-2015 when 2015 in A2
```

Format the cell (Ctrl+1, Number, Custom) as `yyyy` then fill down or right as necessary.

> Do **not** use the [YEAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-C64F017A-1354-490D-981F-578E8EC8D3B9). For **2015**, you will get **1905**. This is because dates are **1** for every day past 31-Dec-1899 and 07-Jul-1905 happens to be the 2015<sup>th</sup> day since 31-Dec-1899.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, where A1 would be the location of the cell that you have stored a four digit year as text:

```
=TEXT("1/1/" & A1,"yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be usable easily for column by dragging, say?

Comment: Yea, just put the formula in the first cell you need it (adjusting the cell reference to be the corresponding row) and the correct column.....for example, if the first "year" you need to convert is in, say, the 5th row and the year is in column is D, you would use =TEXT("1/1/" & D5,"yyyy") then drag it down

Comment: Thanks, it was giving me a percentage, I think though. have to give it another try.

Comment: I think I need =YEAR(something cell column iteration x - xx going here)